# Signo de exclamación en un proyecto de java al crear el main.java

Tags: java

He instalado eclipse y me sale al crear el main me sale esto, hay algo que no e configurado bien?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

No pusiste el error, pero debe decir algo como "main method not found in the class"

Es decir que tu clase no tiene un método principal o un método main.

Esto es porque efectivamente no lo tienes, recuerda siempre el acrónimo psvm... incluso en [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) una forma rápida de crearlo es usar un "template", es decir das enter para estar en una nueva línea y escribes psvm seguido de la tecla <kbd>Tab</kbd> y automáticamente te generará un método main

```
public static void main
```

y puedes pasarle tanto un arreglo como un varargs sin problema, la forma más común es esta:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
}
```